# KISS setup for Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to set up a basic setup for Visual Studio online. I'm interested in two features: Version control (which I have working) and simple ticketing with assignment (think Bugzilla). I'm a company of 1. I don't need to overcomplicate the process with an unnecessary approval processes, team boards, etc. at this stage. I just need a way of tracking features and bugs in a KISS manner. How would I set this up?

Comment: Have you looked at Visual Studio Online? - https://www.visualstudio.com/pricing/visual-studio-online-pricing-vs

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: KISS bug tracking: pen and paper. Once you finish an item strike it out.

Comment: You're using Visual Studio Online for source control. It also has work item tracking. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Online is now [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs), and some links have changed too. Here's the latest docs:

Step 1: [Sign up for Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services)

Step 2: [Connect to Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/team-services/connect-to-visual-studio-team-services) to share code in Git or TFVC from Visual Studio, Eclipse, or Xcode

Step 3: [Create your backlog](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/backlogs/create-your-backlog)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest all the close votes are because you haven't told us what you've tried so far or why the defaults don't work for you.

I'll make it really easy:

Step 1. Create an account at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-au/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs

Step 2. Read and follow the instructions at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/connect-to-visual-studio-online-vs

Step 3. Read https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/work/create-your-backlog-vs and manage your work (features and bugs) as instructed. Ignore the Portfolio backlog stuff since you don't need it.